# LATEX Change the path the output files

Tags: pdftex

Is it possible to change the path of latex output files (e.g .aux, .log, .etc) to a different directory. The main directory is becoming a mess.
Thank you

Comment: You could use the command-line parameter `-output-directory=dir` (just from the help with `pdflatex --help`).

Comment: See [How to change output file directory in latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195596/5764) and [Placing Intermediate and Output Files in Another Folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35052/5764).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.