# More Formats & Options in LyX

Tags: lyx, options, export

In the “File > Export in” there is a paragraph More Formats & Opnions. Show me please how to enter the option. There, where “Send exported file to command” for example, you can enter? Where in the manual about it written? Whether, when jeksportiruesh with options, add LyX in PATH?

Comment: Note that you don't need to enter anything in the text box "Send exported file to command". The main purpose of that option is to select a different format. What exactly do you want to do? i.e., what is your goal that you would like to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know why there's a text box. After all, it is obviously to type some text. What? Although you claim the opposite. Moreover there appears in a ToolTip $$FName. Clearly for keyboard input. In the input box on the right side there is a triangle. Obviously, it is used to select the previously executed commands typed at the keyboard. What, for instance? Can you give examples?

Answer (score 2):

The text box "Send exported file to command" is for advanced users familiar with the command line, who would like to execute a command on the exported file.

For example, I can print a file on the command line with the following:

```
lpr -P MFCL2740DW <filename>
```

This particular command won't work for you unless you use unix and happen to have a printer named "MFCL2740DW". Note that this command has nothing to do with LyX. It is interpreted by a "shell" (e.g., Bash). Although LyX knows nothing about this command, it still allows us to use it from within LyX: if I would like to print a PDF file directly from LyX, I could go to "More Formats & Options", select "PDF (pdflatex)" and in the text box I could put:

```
lpr -P MFCL2740DW $$FName
```

Then, LyX will export the file to PDF, and will then ask the shell to run the following command:

```
lpr -P MFCL2740DW <filename>
```

Again, LyX knows nothing about the command "lpr". All it does is it substitutes `$$FName` for the file name that it exported (that part, LyX does know).

The `lpr` command above is just an example. Any command that you would want to run on an exported file, you can. For example, you could write a command that sends the exported file in an email to your co-author.

Comment: Command line I know. The lucky winner of the printer has not yet become. So I had to make do with what I have.

Comment: At first I was using “File > Export in > More Formats & Opnions” exported in LaTeX(plain) without options. Received file .tex in the folder specified in Tools > Settings > Пути > User directory. I deleted this file. Then I added the following in the text box: pdflatex $$FName. Look like this was so: . The files generated are usually when processing files by LyX, including full .PDF form in a folder C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\bin. Anyone knows how can I change this folder through a text box?

Comment: Forgot to photograph: https://postimg.cc/sBNHgBFN

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355122/latex-change-the-path-the-output-files?noredirect=1&lq=1. The result was that in the text field, you can enter, for example, the following code: pdflatex -output-directory="C:\Zadachi" $$FName. Here is the only way there should be no Cyrillic letters. On the one hand, it is bad: I'm Russian. On the other hand, it is not critical. @scottkosty, Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @D.Suhachev I don't think so. If you want to do more advanced things, I suggest using the `lyx` command from the command line`. e.g., to export a pdf you could do: `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.lyx`. Then the options are limitless.

Comment: I just wanted to know what I can do from the LyX program window. However, if you use the command line, this is a fundamentally different level opportunities. By the way, why did you write that after you export to pdf possibilities are endless? It seems to me that this is not the case. After exporting to .tex, really great opportunities. On the other hand, several commands can hide in a .bat file. And LyX using More Formats & Opnions export file LyX in Latex (plain) with the launch of this .bat file using .lyx file name as a parameter.

Comment: @D.Suhachev I see. I'm actually not familiar at all with the LyX program window. I've tried to experiment a bit so I could answer you questions, but I don't know anything about it.